# colsplit to split into individual characters

Tags: regex, r, reshape2

`colsplit` in package `reshape2` can be used to split character data:

```
colsplit(c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3"), pattern="_", c("Letter", "Number"))
  Letter Number
1      A      1
2      A      2
3      A      3
```

In his paper ["Rehaping data with the Reshape Package"](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper), Hadley Wickham gives an example of using `colsplit` to split data into individual characters.  His example should produce the above from the data `c("A1", "A2", "A3")` which he does by omitting the pattern argument. But this throws an error.

The documentation for `str_split_fixed` which `colsplit` calls says that setting `pattern=""` will split into individual characters, but this does not work.

Is there any way to use `colsplit` so that it splits into individual character.

This is R 3.1.1 and packages are up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to an article about "reshape" but are using "reshape2". The two are not the same and they don't work the same:

```
library(reshape)
library(reshape2)

reshape:::colsplit(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), "", c("V1", "V2"))
#   V1 V2
# 1  A  1
# 2  A  2
# 3  A  3
reshape2:::colsplit(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), "", c("V1", "V2"))
#   V1 V2
# 1 NA A1
# 2 NA A2
# 3 NA A3
```

---

If you don't have to go the `colsplit` way, there are other options:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), "", fixed = TRUE))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "1" 
# [2,] "A"  "2" 
# [3,] "A"  "3"
```

Or, a more general approach (for example characters followed by numbers, not necessarily one character each):

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), 
                        split = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])", 
                        perl = TRUE))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "A"  "1" 
# [2,] "A"  "2" 
# [3,] "A"  "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `qdap`:

```
library(qdap)
colSplit(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), "")

##   X1 X2
## 1  A  1
## 2  A  2
## 3  A  3
```

Comment: I would have green ticked this too!